# Why is the instance of DataLoader a global variable in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, dataset, global-variables, dataloader

I was debugging my `pytorch` code and found that an instance of the class `DataLoader` seems to be a global variable by default. I don't understand why this is the case but I've set up a minimum working example as below that should reproduce my observation. The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df, n_feats, mode):
        data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]).transpose()
        x = data[:, list(range(n_feats))]   # features
        y = data[:, -1]  # target

        self.x = torch.FloatTensor(x)
        self.y = torch.FloatTensor(y)
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]

    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

def prep_dataloader(df, n_feats, mode, batch_size):
    dataset = MyDataset(df, n_feats, mode)
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size, shuffle=False)
    
    return dataloader

tr_set = prep_dataloader(df, 1, 'train', 200)

def test():
    print(tr_set)
```

As shown above, `tr_set` was created before the function `test` and is not passed to `test`. However, running the code above, I got the following result:

```
<torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x7fb6c2ea7610>
```

Originally, I was expecting to get an error like "NameError: name 'tr_set' is not defined". However, the function was aware of `tr_set` and printed the object of `tr_set` even if `tr_set` was not passed as an argument. I'm confused with this because in this case `tr_set` seems like a global variable.

I'm wondering about the reason for this and possible ways that I can prevent it from becoming a global variable. Thank you!

(Update: In case that this matters, I was running the code above in a jupyter notebook.)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have to do with `DataLoader` or how PyTorch functions.

It is not actually a global variable, but since `tr_set` was in the outer scope, in the first level of your file it's accessible to other components of this same file. However this same variable won't be accessible by other modules, for example, hence the fact *it is not* a global variable. The reason function `test` has access to `tr_set` is because of closure made on that variable, *i.e.* the variable is carried through to `test`'s inner scope.